System of rigid bodies: is the net work of some kinds of internal forces always 0?
Suppose we have a system consisting of N rigid bodies. The bodies may exert some forces on one another. These forces, of course, are regarded as "internal" forces of the system.
I'm trying to understand under what circumstances we can say that the internal forces do no net work on the system.
I get that friction forces between the various bodies may indeed do (negative) work, as energy is transformed into heat. I also get that an internal spring force between the bodies may also do work on the system.
However, it is my current understanding that for any system of N rigid bodies, the net work done by all internal forces which belong to any of these groups is always 0:

Normal forces between two bodies
Tension forces exerted by massless strings connecting two bodies (as long as the string is taut and in constant length - even if the bodies are allowed to "swing" or move in arbitrary ways)
"Tension" forces exerted by rigid massless rods connecting two bodies (again, even if the bodies can move arbitrarily while the rod maintains its length)

So when considering a system of N rigid bodies, can we safely assume that the net work of all internal forces belonging to one of the above categories is 0?
Please consider that I have looked around online for a clear answer to this (such as here, Work done by internal forces: when and why is it 0?), but so far haven't found an answer that gave me confidence. Thank you

By definition, forces that are internal to a system do no net work on the system.

@BobD What about, for example, kinetic friction between two objects in the system?


I'm trying to understand under what circumstances we can say that the
internal forces do no net work on the system.

Internal forces of a system are those between parts of a system. These forces do not perform work on the system as a whole.  Internal forces can do work parts of the system, but the net work done on the system as a whole by the work done on the separate parts of the system is zero.
One of the simplest examples involves stacked blocks moving together with static friction between the blocks on a frictionless surface between the lower block and a horizontal supporting surface. A horizontal force is applied to the lower block.
The two blocks exert equal and opposite static friction forces upon one another, per Newton's 3rd law. These are internal forces of the two block system. They do equal and opposite work on each other for a net work of zero. The two block system accelerates as one due to the external force applied to the lower block per Newton's 2nd law.
However, on a free body diagram of the upper block alone, the static friction force exerted upon it by the lower block is the only external horizontal force acting on it and is therefore responsible for the acceleration of the upper block.
A free body diagram on the lower block shows the friction force of the upper block opposing the external force on the lower block. The net force of the two is then responsible for the acceleration of the lower block.
In each of your bulleted scenarios the internal forces described may constitute external forces on other parts of the applicable system.
Hope this helps.

Exactly right, +1. Net work is the net force times the displacement of the center of mass, and internal forces do not contribute to the net force. Internal forces also do not contribute to the total work on a system since they can only move energy around inside the system.

Thanks for answering! Let's say we define our system to include two rigid bodies, A and B. They are both in contact with one another, and moving relative to one another. For example, A is stacked on top of B, and both are sliding in opposite directions. Say that there is kinetic friction between these two bodies. The kinetic friction is of course an internal force of the system. The kinetic friction will slow down the two objects, causing a net reduction in kinetic energy. Thus energy is lost from our two-body system. it has been transformed into heat, which is not included in the system.

Doesn't this mean that net work can be done by internal forces?

@AvivCohn The work done by the external force on the center of mass of the system is the same if the internal friction forces are kinetic or static. The difference is: (1) if static friction all the work done on the system equals the increase in mechanical kinetic energy of the system (2) if kinetic friction not all of the work results in an increase in mechanical kinetic energy. Some results in an increase internal (molecular) kinetic energy due to the internal kinetic friction work.

@AvivCohn To further add, energy is not "lost" in the two body system due to internal kinetic friction. Energy is not "transformed" into heat. It is converted into internal (molecular kinetic) energy resulting in an increase in the temperature of the system. Energy may eventually be lost to a lower temperature surroundings due to heat transfer. But, most importantly, what becomes of the energy transferred to the system as a result of the work is a separate issue from the amount of work done on the system by the external force.
